# How do I setup a Hub Transport Relay Connector in Microsoft Exchange 2003?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, smtp

### Preface

I am employed by a software company and part of our program uses an Exchange server to relay email notifications. The program works as an SMTP client and must be able to send email to external email address.

### Problem

In the past I have assisted our smaller clients with setting up the relay on their Exchange servers. Although I am familiar with the process in Microsoft Exchange 2008, I can't seem to recreate the same thing in Exchange 2003.

First off, here are the settings I use when creating a new relay connector under the Server Configuration>Hub Transport heading in Exchange 2008:

**Authentication Tab**:

- Enable Transport Layer Security (TLS)
- Basic Authentication - Offer basic authentication only after starting
  TLS
- Exchange Server Authentication
- Integrated Windows Authentication

**Network Tab**:

- Under "Use these local IP addresses to receive mail"

  All IPv4 and v6 addresses
- Under the "Receive mail from remote servers that have these IP
  addresses"

  Address range for client

**Permission Groups**:

- Anonymous Users
- Exchange Users
- Legacy Exchange Servers

So, how would I create a relay like the one I have listed in 2003 Exchange?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you may provide.

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to go into Exchange System Manager and setup your relay that way.  After you're in ESM expand the organization, then the servers, then expand the server name, and finally expand Protocols.  Select Relay.  The rest is basically making sure that only the IP of the server/program your company uses is allowed to relay is set right; meaning only allow the one server/program to relay as if you open it up to more than that you could cause yourself to [get blacklisted.](http://gadgetopia.com/post/2607)

[See this link](http://forums.kayako.com/threads/how-to-setup-windows-2003-and-exchange-2003-smtp-relaying.12411/) for a few more details that will help you in case you have questions.

Comment: Let me know how it went for you.

Comment: I will be getting in contact with the client to give it a try today. This looks like it will help.

Comment: Any time my friend.